# Prove that y$_0$ is a strict local maximum of g

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $g$: $R$ → $R$ is twice differentiable at y$_0$, that $g$’(y$_0$) = 0 and that $g$’’(y$_0$) = -2. Prove that y$_0$ is a strict local maximum of $g$.

This is what i'm thinking:

There exists N, a neighborhood of y$_0$ such that $g$(y) < $g$(y$_0$) for all y in N, y ≠ y$_0$. However, I am unsure of how to show this to prove that y$_0$ is a strict local maximum of $g$, but I do think that this method will give me what I need. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

According to Taylor's theorem:

$g(y) =y_0 + \frac{-2(y-y_0)^2}{2!} +(y-y_0)^2h(y)$. Where $\lim_{y\to 0} h(y)=0$

$g(y) =y_0 + (-1+h(y))(y-y_0)^2$

There exists $\delta>0$ such that for all: $-\delta<y<\delta: -1<h(y)<1$

Therefore, for all: $-\delta<y<\delta: g(y)<y_0$

Comment: I am confused by how you would prove the last part explicitly. Could you go more in depth on that part?

Comment: Are you talking about the part that starts with "There exists $\delta$..."?